# Android Studio emulator not showing widgets

Tags: android

I know this isn't a programming question, however this is a frustrating issue that I'm sure has an easy solution,

I have uploaded a screenshot for an error with my android studio emulator whereby any widget I drag and drop, doesn't show in the design view, but it does in the text view.

Any advice on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: you should post your XML code, I think it might contain XML issue.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your theme in your `styles.xml` file to a **Light Theme** should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `Application Theme`

Change your `Application` `Theme` by setting into the `styles.xml` and `Manifest.xml` file

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"  >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Reference:-https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Answer (score 0):

is there `Application theme` error then change into the `style.xml` and `Manifest.xml` file.

otherwise `clean project` or `Rebuild project` your project.

Go To `Build` -> `Rebuild Project` OR `Build` -> `clean Project`.

is there any error then show on `logcat`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your SDK build tools is up-to-date. If not, try updating it first.