# Why won't anything show up in "Design" (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I'm not sure what to do here. I'm pretty new to Android Studio and I'm supposed to see something like this:

(I can't post pictures, but if you go to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui it's figure 3)

But what I see is an empty blue rectangle where I'm supposed to have the squiggle arrows and "Hello World!" I didn't see the "Hello World!" when I had the original template, either. Also, I clicked the "magic wand" thing that infers constraints, but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Are you getting any error msg? Xml preview shows blank when the gradle wont sync successfully.This happens when you have any error in code or error in .gradle file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulator not showing widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739317/android-studio-emulator-not-showing-widgets)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue .

Just open your gradle file (app level) and  set

```
compileSdkVersion to 27

targetSdkVersion to 27
```

And in your dependencies (in the same file) there will be a version 28.0.0 alpha-3

Replace that with 27.1.1 without the alpha-3

It will work

Answer (score 0):

change your style.xml

from

`parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

into

`parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

and build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last two lines of gradel files  that are  Test dependency 
and then  add dependency of  test runner from

> File - >project structure - >app  -> dependency - > test runner
>   (dependency)

and then change it to  `debug implementation.`
I faced the same issue earlier so I tried this and got the result.
And `change the compiled SDK versions dependency from 28.0.0 to 27.1.1`